# Optimizing Alpha and Beta Values for Beta-Binomial Model

Tags: self-study, bayesian, modeling

I am attempting to use a beta-binomial model to predict the number of wins for each NBA basketball team for this current season.

For the prior, I have pre-season win projections for each team. For example, it might be projected that a team will win 41 of 82 games.

For the likelihood, I have the results of the current season so far. About 20 of 82 games have been played, and I have each team's record, say 12-8 as an example.

My goal is to get a posterior distribution that will show the projected win percentage of a team given the prior and likelihood, and allow me to find some confidence / probability interval.

My main question is, how do I determine the parameters for the prior for each team? Is there a way to "train" a model on previous years' data (that has end of season results) to find the optimal values of alpha and beta for the beta prior, or are the prior parameters simply subjective?

Any suggestions for how to utilize the prior information of pre-season projected win totals would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do this would be to take the pre-season projections use them to create the prior. For instance, you say that one team is projected to win 41 of 82 games.  Thus, your prior for the proportion of games won, $\theta$ for that team could be

$$\theta \sim \operatorname{Beta}(\alpha, \beta) =  \operatorname{Beta}(41,41)$$

Note here that $\alpha$ is the number of games won and $\beta$ is the number of games lost.  If after $n$ games $x$ have been won, then the posterior is

$$\theta \vert x \sim \operatorname{Beta}(41+x, 41 + (n-x))$$

Simply add the number of wins to $\alpha$ and the number of losses to $\beta$.

Things become tricky when you have multiple seasons.  Ignoring affects of trades and time, we can assume that the team's $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are somehow distributed.  Our model would then be

$$(\alpha, \beta)^T \sim p(\alpha, \beta) $$

$$ \theta \vert \alpha, \beta \sim \operatorname{Beta}(\alpha, \beta)$$

$$ x \vert \theta, \alpha, \beta \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(\theta, n)$$

A closed form for the likelihood exists, but you'll need to likely use R or python to evaluate some of the expressions.  The model I've written above is actually very similar to Gelman's rat tumor example.  I've written some documentation on how to perform inference on this model for PyMC3 [here](https://docs.pymc.io/notebooks/GLM-hierarchical-binominal-model.html).  That link shows how to perform inference on data using an uninformative prior for the joint distribution of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

You could even go one step further and perform inference for all teams simultaneously by placing a hyper prior on the hyper prior for $alpha$ and $\beta$.  In short, each team's $\alpha$ and $\beta$ come from some population distribution.  The $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are then used to draw a teams' win ratio for any given season, which is then used to draw a number of wins.

Of course, there is no reason to be Bayesian.  You can fit a beta binomial model in R with gamlss.

EDIT 1:

You ask:

> Also, could you speak to the post linked below?

I don't think I will.  There is already an accepted answer with multiple upvotes.

> Could you expand on how using a hierarchical prior could improve the analysis?

If you had one pre-season projection, you could construct a prior as I have outlined in the beginning of this answer.  Since you have multiple pre-season projections, you need a way to combine that information to inform the choice of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.  The hierarchical model I have posted here achieves that.  An implementation is shown in the link I have provided.

Comment: Could you expand on how using a hierarchical prior could improve the analysis? I have the pre-season projections for each year, which I believe are historically pretty accurate. Also, could you speak to the post linked below? I believe I am trying to do something similar, by training on data from previous seasons to find optimal alpha and beta values, and then using some sort of average to predict the current season. Please let me know if this isn't clear. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54505173/finding-alpha-and-beta-of-beta-binomial-distribution-with-scipy-optimize-and-log

Comment: @KevinM. See my edits